# Is is possible to stop a GM radio theft lock light from blinking

Tags: chevrolet, audio, security, colorado

This question is about a 2004 Chevy Colorado Pickup with a CD radio.

I was asked to find out why there's a light that blinks constantly when the ignition is turned off.

I think I've identified it as an indicator that theft lock is enabled. (I don't mean that it's locked. The radio works just fine. I think it's meant as visual a deterrent to radio thieves)

Short of disassembling the radio and removing the LED, is there a way to disable that blinking light?

Comment: Sounds more like a theft deterrent showing that the immobiliser/alarm is active.

Comment: Yeah, most cars have something similar. Also, who steals original GM radios anymore?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My '04 Chevy has a similar light; I don't think it's possible to disable it.

If it is bothersome, I would just mask over it with a piece of non-clear tape.

You could use Blu-tac as well.

The nice thing with both hacks is they are reversible.

Answer (score 3):

On VWs, I *think* (i.e., it looks like, but I haven't checked the schematic) that the blinking light – which is integrated with the door lock button – flashes when the car is locked.

So, have you checked that the radio is getting all of the right inputs? If there is an always on power, it is there and getting power? Is there an input from the locking system? See if you can figure out what turns on the light, I'd be willing to be that it is an external input.

Failing that @Zaid's plan sounds good, cheap, and easily reversible. Cut out a piece of black electrical tape with a hole punch and it will look nice and professional.

Comment: I like the hole - punch idea!